# Bad receiver type 'void' error in XCode 5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

I got the "Bad receiver type 'void' " error in Xcode 5. I am using the following code,

Method definition :

```
- (BOOL)allItemsSelectedFrom:(NSSet *)original selectedItems:(NSMutableArray *)selecteds{

    NSLog(@"original = %@", original);

    for (id object in original)
        if([[object display] intValue]==1)
        if (![selecteds containsObject:[object name]])
            return NO;
    int k=0;
    for (id object in original)
    {
        if([[object display] intValue]==1)
            k++;
    }
    //if(k==[selecteds count] && ([selecteds count]!=0))
    if(k==[selecteds count])
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Method call :

```
        BOOL allItemsSelected = [self allItemsSelectedFrom:profile.chemotherapies selectedItems:chemotherapies];
```

**How can I fix this issue in Xcode 5?**

**One more thing, Its working fine in Xcode 4.6.3, there is no error occurred..**

[image]

Comment: Seems like `[object display]` is **void** method. `-(void)display;`. Then It will return nothing so you can not convert it into `integer`.

Comment: Also there is need to type cast to call object's method. example: `YourClass *obj = (YourClass *)object;` then call `display` method via `[obj display]`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it doesn't have anything to do with xcode. it haas to do with the base sdk headers
the compiler doesn't know  what method display to use as there are many

add a cast from ID to the object you are working with so that it uses the right display method

Comment: there are N methods and xcode doesn't know which to take. it is a common issue if you rely on id too much

Answer (score 1):

Multiple `display` methods are visible to compiler (see `[CALayer (void)display]`) and since, you are using `id` it could be any one of them.

Instead of `id` in the loop, use the actual class:

```
for (YourClass *object in original)
```

This will give you more type checking and give hint to Xcode about the return type.